# HTML files sometimes don't load

Tags: html, css

I actually have a few questions, the first being why my CSS files are not loading? It should be stated that I'm very new to HTML and CSS and this is actually my first project so don't be harsh? Also, sometimes my videos don't load, like I have a page for memes and it just gives me a black video player. I decided to ignore it and focus on CSS and then was testing out my page and the memes loaded. My final question is how can I add multiple videos/audios together. For example if I have three audio files like so

audio one
audio two
audio three

only the first one will appear. Do I need to add something? Here are all my files, and some of the video files were too large to upload.
https://github.com/abdulahad12345/MyWebsite

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You should define your CSS rules inside `{}` braces but you're using `()` parentheses.
   Next, you need to separate property and value with colon(:) not equals to (=).

Example of valid CSS rule:

```
background-color: blue;
```

2. To add multiple videos on a page, you can do:

```
<video controls src="videos1.mp4" type="video/mp4"></video>

<video controls src="videos2.mp4" type="video/mp4"></video>
```

If you have same video in different formats for multiple versions of browsers support, then you can use `<source src="..... />` like you've done in your project. By doing so, the browser will try to play the first supported formats. Otherwise you can simply define source in `<video>` tag as example above.

You can do the same for audio files as well.

Comment: Thank you thank you. I didn't notice I did parentheses. It's working now!.

Answer (score 0):

to reload your css you must do ctrl+F5 and not just F5

Comment: I should add I'm using Brackets but alright

Comment: Edit: Did not work